# How to organize this excel page in proper rows and columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, visualization

I want to organize this sheet in proper rows and columns. can anyone suggest to me the steps to do it?

[image]

Comment: I think `Text to Column` method would be best choice.

Comment: @Harun24hr: I'm always using the "Help" to find this feature, in which ribbon is it located in the latest Excel versions?

Comment: In `DATA` tab `Data Tools` section.

Comment: [Split text into different columns with the Convert Text to Columns Wizard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7)

Comment: @Harun24hr, Thank you for the solution. The Data Tools approach worked for me.

Comment: @Ankit I have added this to my answer. You may accept (tick mark) my answer to treat this thread as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `Text to Column` feature. It is in `DATA` tab under `Data Tools` section.

Or if you want to go with Excel formula then could use-

```
=DROP(REDUCE(0,A1:INDEX(A1:A50000,COUNTA(A1:A50000)),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b,"|")))),1)
```

Little bit simpler approach.

```
=DROP(REDUCE(0,TOCOL(A:A,1),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,TEXTSPLIT(b,"|")))),1)
```

[image]